# How can I compare 2 characters which belong to the same string?

Tags: c++, string

The data type is string and I want to compare 2 characters of that string and swap those two
Example: 
string x="ABDCBC"

and after comparing the characters I want the following output :
ABDCCB

Comment: Did you try something already?

Comment: Comparing means what? What is the idea behind it? Compare every character with every character or only characters next to each other? Please specify your requirements better. Possible also mention what you already tried. This board is here to help, not to solve problems for other people. Show that you already tried.

Answer (score 1):

**Here is a simple `swap` function :**

`i1` and `i2` parameters are indexes. They are the position of the characters you want to swap inside the `str` `string`.

```
bool swap(string &str, size_t i1, size_t i2)
{
    if (i1 >= str.size() || i2 >= str.size()) // Out of bounds
        return (false);
    char tmp = str[i1];
    str[i1] = str[i2];
    str[i2] = tmp;
    return (true);
}
```

**I made a little demo. You can test it here : https://ideone.com/4OQdib**